# How to split a list of data frames based on the variables' class?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, split, lapply

I have a list of more than 600 data frames, which doesn't have the same exact type of variables. Sometimes the class is different to the desired one because for instance there is a letter just before an integer and that makes the whole column a character instead (just because of a silly typo...) What I need to do is to identify which of those data frames do not have the desired variables' classes and modify it so I can work with all data for different purposes (summarize, analyses, etc). (I asked for similar help but regarding the column names here [How to split a list of data frames based on its column names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51669682/how-to-split-a-list-of-data-frames-based-on-its-column-names) )

I am trying to create two lists from the main one based on the desired order and classes of the variables. For that I am trying to do the following:

```
v1 <- c(1:15)
v2 <- c(20:34)
v3 <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o")
v3b <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o")

df1 <- data.frame(v1, v2, v3)
df2 <- data.frame(v1, v2, v3)
df3 <- data.frame(v1, v2, v3b)

df1[1,2] <- "m3" 

mylist <- list(df1, df2, df3)

str(mylist[[1]]) # here you can see the class of each variable and how in df1 the class has been changed from integer to character
d_class <- sapply(mylist[[2]], class) # this is how I get the desired class

# now I try to alternatives to identify the dfs with the undesired structure:
#1
list_a <- list()
list_a <- lapply(mylist, function(x) class(x) == d_class) # do not work
grep('FALSE', list_a)

#2
list_b <- list()
list_b <- split(mylist,sapply(mylist,function(x) 
identical(class(x),d_class)))
```

As you can see I always get the all the data frames in return and the code doesn't recognize the desired class even if it is previously specified.

Does anyone know what is wrong with this code?

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is a `list` of `data.frame`, the `class` is `data.frame`.  We need to loop throuh the datasets to get the class of individual columns

```
lapply(mylist, function(x) sapply(x, class) == d_class)
```

If we need a `vector` of logical index to find those datasets that have the same `class` as in the 'd_class', wrap with `all` on the logical vector

```
sapply(mylist, function(x) all(sapply(x, class) == d_class))
```